# Mobile Devices Advice

Tags: mobile, windows-mobile, signature

I would like to develop on a mobile device, probably with Windows Mobile platform, which device would you guys recommend for me to use? But one requirement on the device is that I need that device to be able to capture signature (human writing on the device).

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like any PocketPC (or "Professional") device would do.  Personally I currently have an HTC Touch Pro, which would be suitable for what you describe.  For testing purposes, it might also be a good idea to also test on a device with smaller resolutions (I have an HTC Elfin for example that would do well here, but it shows its age..).  Or on the emulator provided with the SDKs.

However some of the newer ones have capacitive touch screens and no stylus.  (For example HTC HD2.)  So while HD2 is otherwise an excellent phone, capturing a human writing on it probably wouldn't work as well as older devices with resistive screens and a stylus.

Answer (score 0):

Any Windows Mobile 6.0/6.1 based phone with [resistive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistive_touchscreen) touch screen. A good example is HTC Touch Pro2.

Also, some S60 5th edition phones, such as N97, may be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the languages you intend to use to write the application. 
If it's Java, I'd go with an android system.
If you're a c# coder I'd say any windows device would be ok.. You could likely get one on EBay for dirt cheep and for the most part you can be sure your code will run on most of them (I know this is a generality), especially if you keep the code simple. 
If you're a c++ developer then the same as above, any pocket PC/winmobile will do. 
If you own a mac, and you've written apps in objective c then IPhone is a good choice.

In part you have to base decisions like this on what you know going in.
If you're a blank slate.... well then you've got to figure out what direction you want to take your knowledge. I've personally picked Java and Android because I've recently been convinced it's the road to the future.